# How do I create an iterator in Hadoop that goes from 1..N?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I want to use Hadoop as a simple system for managing a grid job. (I was previously doing this with SGE and pbs/Torque but we are moving to Hadoop.) I have 1000 ZIP files, each containing 1000 files, for a total of 1M files. I want to upload them all to Amazon S3. Ideally I want to do this without putting the files in HDFS. All of the files are WWW accessible.

What I want to do is:

1. Have an iterator that goes from 0..999
2. For each map job, get the iterator and:

   - fetch the ZIP file (it's about 500MB, so it will be written to temp storage)
   - read the ZIP directory.
   - extract each file and upload it to Amazon S3.

I know how to do the ZIP file magic in Java and Python. My question is this: How do I create an iterator so that the mapper will get the numbers 0..999?

The output of the reducer will be the amount of time that each took to upload.  I then want a second map/reduce step that will produce a histogram of the times. So I guess the correct thing is for the times and failure codes to be written into HDFS (although it seems like it would make a lot more sense just to write them to an SQL database).

I'm interested in doing this in both traditional MapReduce (preferably in Python, but I will do it in Java or Scala if I have to), and in Spark (and for that I need to do it in Scala, right?). Although I can see that there's no real advantage to doing it in Spark.

Comment: In simple words .. You want each of the zip file to be extracted which has 1000 files in it. And then upload each file with a number? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark you can simply parallelize over range:

- Python

  ```py
  n = ...  # Desired parallelism 

  rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000), n)

  def do_something_for_side_effects(i): ...
  rdd.foreach(do_something_for_side_effects)
  ```

  or

  ```py
  def do_something(i): ...
  rdd.map(do_something).saveAsTextFile(...)  # Or another save* method
  ```
- Scala

  ```scala
  val n: Int = ???  // Desired parallelism 

  val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 until 1000, n)

  def doSomethingForSideEffects(i: Int): Unit = ???
  rdd.foreach(doSomethingForSideEffects)
  ```

  or

  ```scala
  def doSomething(i: Int) = ???
  rdd.foreach(doSomething).saveAsTextFile(...)  // Or another save* method
  ```

Comment: That's very nice. Is there any way to do this reasonably on traditional MapReduce? Also, the reference I read states that Side Effects aren't handled well in Spark at this point. Is that still true?

Comment: The simplest thing? Just write numbers from 0 to 999 to the file and pass it as an input to the job though getting sensible splits can be harder.